# Initiating sagemaker training job from aws glue job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-sagemaker

Trying to run the following code through an AWS Glue job. The file mentioned in scipt_path is in the same S3 bucket folder as the script for the glue job. However i still get FileNotFound error. Where should the script file be located for it to be found?

```
script_path = 'personalized_books_recommendation_script.py'
sess = sagemaker.Session()

# run the Scikit-Learn script
sklearn = SKLearn(
    entry_point=script_path,
    instance_type=instance_type_train,
    instance_count=instance_count_train,
    role=get_execution_role(),
    sagemaker_session=sess,
    framework_version=FRAMEWORK_VERSION
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

When launching an Amazon SageMaker job with the [SageMaker SDK](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/sklearn/sagemaker.sklearn.html#scikit-learn-estimator), 'entry_point' expects an absolute or relative path in the file system of the environment from which the call is executed. In this case, having the AWS Glue job script in the same S3 bucket and prefix does not help.

If you want to have your code in S3, you should have it together with its  dependencies in a .tar.gz file and use the 'source_dir' parameter pointing to it.

In addition, may I ask why are you launching an Amazon SageMaker training job from an AWS Glue job? I would run the both jobs separately as steps in a pipeline ([AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) could be a good option to orchestrate it).

Comment: Yes i figured it out. I am launching sagemaker training job from glue because i am using glue workflow for orchestration.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense.